# Not getting any items (pokeballs or anything else) at poke stops

Tags: pokemon-go

Today, i stopped at 4 different pokestops multiple times but couldnt get any pokeballs.  My bag is not full but it just spins but not give anything.  I am using pokemon trainer club account.  We do use the same account on 2 iphones (and both have the same problem).

Comment: This happens sometimes. Usually occurs when there are server latency issues.

Comment: Is the PokeStop changing color from Blue to Purple?

Comment: No.  Pokestop color stayed blue

Comment: If it stays blue try closing and reopening the game and checking again. This forces an update from the server and will sometimes change the color and you can check your journal and see you might have picked up the items anyway.

Comment: You may be getting soft banned for sharing an account. Can you still catch Pokemon or do they run away after your first hit?

Comment: Also, does the Pokestop have a picture of what the stop is? If the circle is white, I've found that spinning it does nothing, and eventually leads to a try again. If the picture loads, the stop typically works fine.

Comment: I didn't see any pokemon to try and capture.  I sure hope its not a soft ban.  We just want to play the game as a family so we downloaded on 2 phones.

Comment: Kaizerwolf, pokestop did have a picture in the circle.

Comment: seems like we cant capture pokemons either.  maybe it is using the account on two phones.  if it is, thats a bummer.

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all. The other question's solution is "Your bag is full", however here the question clearly says "My bag is not full". Please reopen.

Comment: @Aequitas: I get the exact same symptoms without sharing accounts, so it is not a soft ban problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a connection issue. If your connection is bad, or the servers are under heavy load, PokeStops and Gyms will struggle to fully load in, not giving you items.

On a side note, if the PokeStop is staying blue, but saying "Try again later," check your bag, as you probably got the items anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a simular issue lately, but here's what I was able to determine:

- If I started Pokemon Go on **Data**, then moved onto **WiFi*** (as in coming back home, and getting in wifi range): No issues. (Can see the image of a pokestop and have pokemon spawn nearby.)
- If I started Pokemon Go on **Wifi**, then move onto **data*** (as walking out of of my house, then driving away): issues with Pokestops that spin but never drop anything, and are missing their location picture. The "loading" Pokeball continually spins as well.

I cannot tell if this issue is a phone or carrier issue, but the fix for this is to **terminate/kill the app, then reopen it**. Closing the app and leaving it memory will not close the connection.  It's that reconnect part which fixes the issue if this is what you're experiencing..

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen multiple times when there are server issues or I have poor connectivity. Check to make sure you have a good signal or try again later and see if the issue continues.

On a side note this doesn't mean you didn't get anything every time. You can check your journal and it will sometimes show you got the items anyway without them popping up.

Comment: These are the same Pokestops I went to last two days and always gotten the balls.  and 4 different stops too, hence didnt think it was latency issue.  will try later in the afternoon at different pokestops

Comment: @c4rnil: Your location only affects how strong your connection is to your data service. Niantic's servers have their own latency issues, especially with how popular the game is. That's the real limiting factor for your problem right now.

Comment: Thanks.  It could be just that and hope its just that and not because the app is on two phones:)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the servers or the app or both kinda derp. Check your journal, however, and you should see the items you received.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a soft-ban because of sharing the account. Try to use it on only one phone.

Comment: I get the exact same symptoms without sharing accounts, so it is probably not a soft-ban problem.